# Windows Form .net where i can found a component like this in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, windows-forms-designer

I am trying to found the best control in Vb.net that makes me presenting the date in this form, what is important is to have multiple data in one cell ( student1, student2,student3) and image beside each student ( for phone ) , it look like the Datagridview contrôle does not provide this ( at least not by default).

[image]

Comment: Could have sworn I've already seen this question today

Comment: There's no reason you couldn't build something yourself using a TableLayoutPanel.

Comment: This isn't the site to come for to get recommendations.  plenty of 3rd party add ons and tool suits have some very capable layout controls.  Or implement your own interface using things like the TableLayoutPanel, User Controls, owner draw or combo of all of that

Comment: @Hursey if Stackoverflow isn't (anymore) the site to come and ask for the best recommendations to do things, I wonder then what is the purpose. Any way, Thank u

Comment: Could always try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/.  And you may want to consider a refresher on the site tour.  Very clearly stated in there about asking for recommendations

Answer (score 0):

I will use the Tablelayoutpanel and customise it

one more thing, if Stackoverflow isn't (anymore)  the site to come and ask for the best recommendations to do things, I wonder then what is the purpose...